# Close other buffers with projectile

Tags: projectile

Projectile has a function to close all buffers related to a project (projectile-kill-buffers). Normally I also open non project related files during the day or emacs opens them when I'm stepping through compiler errors. Is there a way to close all buffers except project and special buffers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the below function to your emacs init and call it via `M-x`.

By default this function will kill all buffers except the ones that belong to a `projectile` project or are special.

The same function will also kill special buffers (except *scratch* and *Messages*) if called with a prefix like `C-u`.

```el
(defun modi/kill-non-project-buffers (&optional kill-special)
  "Kill buffers that do not belong to a `projectile' project.

With prefix argument (`C-u'), also kill the special buffers."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((bufs (buffer-list (selected-frame))))
    (dolist (buf bufs)
      (with-current-buffer buf
        (let ((buf-name (buffer-name buf)))
          (when (or (null (projectile-project-p))
                    (and kill-special
                         (string-match "^\*" buf-name)))
            ;; Preserve buffers with names starting with *scratch or *Messages
            (unless (string-match "^\\*\\(\\scratch\\|Messages\\)" buf-name)
              (message "Killing buffer %s" buf-name)
              (kill-buffer buf))))))))
```